# foreach table laravel when data 5 <br>

Tags: html, laravel

I have table html

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>data 1</td>
    <td>data 2</td>
    <td>data 3</td>
    <td>data 4</td>
    <td>data 5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>data 1</td>
    <td>data 2</td>
    <td>data 3</td>
    <td>data 4</td>
    <td>data 5</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

i want to dynamic table use foreach from database.
if `data > 5`, then create new `<tr>` .
i want view grid table dynamic...
any body help?

Comment: Please show dummy data and how you're writing the table view atm

Comment: data just id and name.. @SérgioReis

Comment: Is data coming from the server?

Comment: data is load from localhost..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Collection::chunk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-chunk) method to break data into multiple chunks:

**Controller:**

```
public function index() {
     $data = Model::all()->chunk(5);
     return view('view', ['data' => $data]);
}
```

**View:**

```
<table>
    @foreach($data as $chunk)
        <tr>
            @foreach($chunk as $value)
                <td>{{ $value->name }}</td>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Comment: im getting error Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: $data= data::latest();
        $data2 = data::all()->chunk(5);
        return view('pages.test', compact($data,$data2));

Comment: `compact($data,$data2)` here where you have error, it should look like this `compact('data','data2')`

Comment: I think one more step left, transform collection to array by using this: `$data2 = data::all()->chunk(5)->toArray();`

Comment: opps work, i wrong name variable, variable data have 2.. sorry :D.. thank

Comment: So it worked without using toArray() method ? or what ?

Comment: without, i just change name variable data to datas in controller. :D

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an array like:

```
$data =["data1","data2","data3","data4","data5","data1","data2","data3","data4","data5"];
$collected = collect($data)->chunk(5);
// return this to view
.
.
.
// view.blade.php
@foreach($collected as $group)
<tr>
@foreach($group as $row)
   {{$row}}
@endforeach
</tr>
@endforeach
```